# How convert PFObject to string? - Swift 1.2 Xcode 6.4 and Parse.com -

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, option-type

This is part of another question, but since that original question got an answer, it will be more clear in the future if I face this problem here, single way.

EDIT: added an exception breakpoint, at runTime appeared this:

[image]

I got this message: **Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'PFObject' always fails**

here the warning screenshot [image]

console also says "**Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' (0x10980e1e8) to 'NSString' (0x10b8e78e0).
(lldb)** "

In my opinion I'm failing to access data the proper way, but don't know where

thanks in advance

```
//
//  TimelineTVC2.swift
//  lug15ParseChat
//
//






import UIKit
import Parse

class TimelineTVC2: UITableViewController {


    var timelineData : [String] = []


    func loadData() {

        timelineData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)          //erase previus contents

        var findTimeLineDataQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages")

        findTimeLineDataQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                for singleObject in objects! {
                    self.timelineData.append(singleObject as! String)
                }
                let reversedArray : Array = self.timelineData.reverse()  //remeber always!
                self.timelineData = reversedArray as Array

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }



    //    MARK: Parse
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.loadData()

        if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
            var loginAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign up / login", message: "please sign up or login", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            loginAlertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
                textfField in
                textfField.placeholder = "Your username"
            })

            loginAlertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
                textfField in
                textfField.placeholder = "Your password"
                textfField.secureTextEntry = true
            })

            //            MARK: login action in the array
            loginAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login Action", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                alertAction in
                let textFields : NSArray = loginAlertController.textFields!
                let usernameTextField : UITextField = textFields[0] as! UITextField
                let passwordTextField : UITextField = textFields[1] as! UITextField

                //MARK: Parse login problem - 15:39
                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text){
                    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if user != nil {
                        println("login success!")
                    } else {
                        println("login failed!")
                    }
                }
            }))

            //            MARK: sign up action in the array
            loginAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                alertAction in
                let textFields : NSArray = loginAlertController.textFields!
                let usernameTextField : UITextField = textFields[0] as! UITextField
                let passwordTextField : UITextField = textFields[1] as! UITextField

                var messageSender = PFUser() //16:42
                messageSender.username = usernameTextField.text
                messageSender.password = passwordTextField.text

                messageSender.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        println("sign up successful")
                    } else {
                        //                        let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as! String
                        let errorString = error!.localizedDescription
                        println(errorString)
                    }
                })

            }))


            self.presentViewController(loginAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }






    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return timelineData.count
    }




    //MARK: WARNING! Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'PFObject' always fails
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : SweetTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellReuseID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SweetTableViewCell

        var textMessage : PFObject = self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as! PFObject

        cell.sweetTextView.text = textMessage["content"] as! String

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is convert a whole `PFObject` to a `String`, which as the compiler points out will never work. What you need to do instead is access the fields inside the `PFObject` that contain the strings you're trying to get. So for instance, on the `User` class, the email field is a string. In order to get that from the `PFUser` (which is a subclass of `PFObject`), you need to access the field, and then assign *that* to the string. It would look like this (pretending that `singleObject` is a `PFUser` because I don't know your fields):

```
for singleObject in objects! {
    if let stringData = singleObject["email"] as? String {
        timelineData.append(stringData)
    }
}
```

Another option, only the syntax is different.

```
for singleObject in objects! {
    if let stringData = singleObject.objectForKey("email") as? String {
        timelineData.append(stringData)
    }
}
```

Both will work and give you the desired result.

Also, as an additional point, instead of reversing the array after you've put the objects in it, you can simply call `findTimeLineDataQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")`. This will save you some overhead since it will be done before the data is returned to you, rather than it being done on the device.

EDIT: To fix `cellForRowAtindexPath:`

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : SweetTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellReuseID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SweetTableViewCell

    cell.sweetTextView?.text = self.timelineData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

You were trying to convert the strings that you just took out of your `PFObject` and turn them back into `PFObject`s. Since you have the text you want to display now, in your `cellForRowAtindexPath:` all you have to do is access the value stored at that location in your `timelineData` array.

Comment: added your first solution, and solved first issue!, now remains the second message "Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'PFObject' always fails" from cellFromRowAtIndexPath I have Messages class with a message column on Parse. I should "aim" to that column, but how?

Comment: I updated my answer to resolve your second issue @biggreentree.

Comment: great! solved! is there a way you could think of, for making me possible to better understand this kind of accesses? for example .sweetTextView?. what if the optional is nil? should I mind about it in this case?

Comment: In that case, it's something called optional chaining. What this means is that if any part of the object, in this case it's `textLabel` is nil, during runtime it won't try and execute any code after that, so you don't have to worry about a nil case. In terms of accessing the image, well we checked for that before we added to the array so there's no way `timelineData[indexPath.row]` would ever return nil.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do here is cast a **property** of `PFObject` - not the object itself. In the example below, `someProperty` is the field on the `Messages` object that you wish to access.

It should look something like this:

```
for singleObject in objects! {
    var someProperty = singleObject["somePropertyName"] as String
    self.timelineData.append(someProperty)
}
```